# Formula for the terms of the sequence defined by $a_0 = 1$, $a_1 = -2$ and $a_{n}=-4 a_{n-1}-4 a_{n-2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

> Let $a_{n}$ be the sequence recursively defined by $a_{0} = 1$, $a_{1} = -2$,  and for $n\geq 2$,  $a_{n}=-4 a_{n-1}-4 a_{n-2}$. Use strong induction to show that $a_{n}$ = $(-2)^n$ for all n.

This is what I have so far:

Basis:

- $a_{0}=1=(-2)^0$
- $a_{1}=-2=(-2)^1$

The statement is true when $n=0$ and when $n=1$.

Not sure how to go on from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Complete_induction) of  strong induction,

Let $\displaystyle a_n=(-2)^n$ for $1\le n\le m$

$\implies \displaystyle a_{m+1}=-4a_m-4a_{m-1}=-4(-2)^m-4(-2)^{m-1}=-4(-2)^{m-1}(-2+1)=(-2)^2\cdot(-2)^{m-1}=(-2)^{m+1}$

Comment: I understand what is going on. But just for learning purposes can you explain what you are doing as you do the strong induction?

Comment: @Mark, please find link added in the answer

Comment: I don't understand the notation of the definition of strong induction.

Comment: @Mark, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrincipleofStrongInduction.html and http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrincipleofStrongInduction.html

Comment: @Mark, induction is: show that the first domino falls, and that every domino that falls knocks the next one; then you can be sure all dominoes fall. Strong induction is, show that the first domino falls, and that if all dominoes up to a certain point fell, then the next one falls too. So, strong induction -although equivalent- allows you to use as argument a stronger assumption ("all dominoes up to a point") to prove that the next one also falls. Stronger assumptions make proofs easier.